# Symmetricds support spatialite database?

Tags: symmetricds, spatialite

How can I configure the symmetric db engine to replicate a SpatiaLite database ?
If there are no way what's the steps to add a new platform to symmetric db?

Answer (score 0):

No, there’s no support

Fork the source code from developer’s repository, find a support, try to replicate it and after testing submit a patch back

Answer (score 0):

Have tried using the SQL Lite dialect?  It appears the SpatiaLite database is just an extension to SQL Lite for spatial data.   SymmetricDS works with Oracle and Postgres spatial data out of the box.   So treating it as a SQL Lite node may be sufficient.  If there are additional libraries that need added you can put them in the lib folder of SymmetricDS and restart.